# How to implement multithread/task observer pattern?

Tags: c#, multithreading, task, observable

I am working on a DAQ/instrumentation suite that should push large amounts of (double type) array data from/to HW devices e.g. DAQ boards or soundcards. Each HW device has a buffer, and will invoke callbacks when input buffer is full. The buffer should be pushed the buffer to several SW instruments e.g. oscillosope and spectrum analyzer. Each instrumennt as well as device driver should run in separate threads/tasks. My intention is to process about 1 Million doubles point per second.

For pushing data I have looked at IObservable/IObserver and I made an initial test which works without threads. The data type looks like this

```
public interface IAnalogInArrayData
{
        int NumberOfChannels { get; }
        int NumberOfPoints { get; }
        string[] XUnits { get; }
        string[] YUnits { get; }

        double[][] GetXData();
        double[][] GetXYata();
}
```

The double[][] could be up to [8][10000] and be updated every 100 msec.

Now I want to move to multi-threading (or tasks). I did some research and I am somewhat confused over the available alternatives:

- according to an old SOF post (unfortunately I lost it), IObservable/IObserver should be replaced with Reactive extensions and Subject. However according to MSDN the Rx intro page is not updated anymore, but there is no suggestions to what should be used instead.
- TPL: this seems to be a very high performing multithreading framework but I got lost in all options,

How can I make IObservable/IObserver thread safe?
Should I skip threads and use tasks directly?
Should I use Rx, TPL or am I  missing any alternatives? 
What are the pros and cons of each approach? 
Feedback is greatly appreciated.

For pushing data I have looked at IObservable/IObserver and I made an initial test which works without threads, see attached code.

Comment: You haven't posted any code. In any case, the GOF Observer pattern has nothing to do with event processing, which seems to be what you want. The `IObservable/IObserver` interfaces in the BCL don't implement any event processing functionality, that's part of Rx. TPL is the *low level* underlying technology that's used for parallelism and concurrency. Rx can use tasks for sources and subscribers for example

Comment: You should explain what you want *without* describing what you think the attempted solution is. Rx is a higher-level library that allows analyzing events using eg windowing functions. TPL *Dataflow* allows you to create a pipeline of independent processing blocks that can easily handle high volumes - it originated in the Robotics runtime of the 2010s. It won't analyze the data though,you'll have to write that code yourself, eg inside one of the blocks.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - Thanks for the feedback, this is my fiits post. I will rephrase the queston and explain what I want to do.

Comment: it's not a matter of SO experience. A lot of people confuse parallelism, concurrency and asynchronous execution even though they refer to completely different things. In this case, given the expected traffic, 1M/sec, making the wrong choice can hurt a lot

Comment: Rx is *perfect* for analysis - you can calculate averages, min, max per window simply by using the correct window operator in a LINQ query. By default though, the observable (the source) the operators and the subscribers (the instruments) run on the same thread. With 1M/sec that's a problem. You can configure each part to run on a separate thread though. On the other hand, each Dataflow block runs on its own task but analyzing stuff needs custom code. You probably need *both* to handle this traffic

Comment: Rx is generally very good at this kind of thing, but it may not be fast enough. Neither might TPL. You may have to resort to threads with light-weight locking. I'd love to suggest a solution with Rx, but you've hardly given enough detail to do that. Could you provide a [mcve]?